# How do I treat a plain-text message as a numerical value (for encryption algorithms)?

Tags: encryption, casting

I am learning about cryptographic algorithms and in the process am attempting to implement some well known schemes. I understand the mathematical explanations behind RSA and El Gamal, but am currently unable to test my implementations of either. The underlying problem is that I cannot see the way to convert plain text into a manipulatable number.

***For Example:***

```
Message = "This is a message I want to encrypt";
int x = (int)Message;
Encrypt(x,key);
```

In my mind, it should be possible to cast a string to an integer, but doing so in a method similar to the above example doesn't work. How can I turn a plain-text message into a numerical value (and later back into a plain-text value) for the purposes of encryption?

Comment: If the accepted answer truly addresses your real question, this is the most poorly-worded question I've seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are usually two steps to converting a string to an integer. The first is to convert each character into a small integer and then convert the resulting sequence of small integers into a large integer. For example, in Java or C# you can easily convert the string into a byte array representing its UTF-8 encoding. Then, by treating the byte array as a base-256 integer, you can convert it to a large integer. Every BigInteger package that I am aware of has a constructor that will accept an array of bytes, as well as a method that will go the other way and take the BigInteger and return an array of bytes.

Answer (score 3):

The numbers used in Diffie-Hellman and RSA are really large, so libraries that implement them work with specialized types that can represent numbers with thousands of bits. Casting to an `int` would, at best, hold 32 or 64 bits.

Most of these libraries are able to convert a string of bytes to their big integer type. Converting a string to a big integer usually requires the intermediate step of applying a character encoding to convert the string of characters to a string of bytes.

Comment: I understand that the numbers in real use cases are large, but I am currently testing relatively small numbers just to make sure my implementations are correct.

Comment: @XBigTK13X - A cast still won't work in any "managed" language like Java or C#. C or C++ would let you do it with a cast, but only for 4 or 8 characters, depending on your `int` size. In Java or C#, you need to convert the string to bytes, then pack the bytes into an `int` with bit operations. I would show an example, but your implementation won't be correct if it doesn't operate on some sort of `BigInteger` type. If you used primitive `int` types in your implementation, it won't work without changes.

Comment: Also, all of the test vectors that are published in the specifications use large integers. It's also extremely helpful to test with other software, to ensure that you inter-operate successfully. Of course, that will require using large integers too.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to cast a string of text into a numerical value, you can simply add the ASCII numerical value of each character. This is, of course, not a reliable checksum, and you may run into problems if a text has *higher* unicode values.

In C you can do (quick and dirty):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
 int k = 0;
 int value = 0;
 char text[]="this is a piece of text.";
 char c;
 for(k=0; k<strlen(text); k++){
   c = text[k];
   value = value + c;
   printf("char %c has value %d\n", c, c);
 }
 printf("total value is: %d\n", value);
 return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
char t has value 116
char h has value 104
char i has value 105
char s has value 115
char   has value 32
char i has value 105
char s has value 115
char   has value 32
char a has value 97
char   has value 32
char p has value 112
char i has value 105
char e has value 101
char c has value 99
char e has value 101
char   has value 32
char o has value 111
char f has value 102
char   has value 32
char t has value 116
char e has value 101
char x has value 120
char t has value 116
char . has value 46
total value is: 2147
```

Notice that this is by no means a secure or efficient approach to ensuring that a file is what it is supposed to be (a checksum). If you want a "value" assigned to a given stream of text, try SHA-1 hash function.

Comment: This won't allow recovery of the message. There are many, many possible ways to create a sum of "2147".

Comment: Yep. This is only a way to "convert a string into a number" - a mediocre checksum. For the question of creating a reliable encryption algorithm... I'm afraid that's a whole different (and difficult) ball-game.

Comment: "How can I turn a plain-text message into a numerical value *(and later back into a plain-text value)* ... ?"